# Adding a specific search error into a table when there is an invalid search

Tags: javascript, jquery

When there is an invalid search my program gets a a label from a database and enters it into a var:

```
searchError.add(ss.getLabel("UASJSNSER", request));
```

When the user searches something a table is filled with all the possible results.  When the user makes an invalid search I need the table to be filled with the label and not to be left bank.

```
$('#SearchResults').isEmpty(function(){
    searchError.add(ss.getLabel("UASEXFERR", request));
    ('#SearchResults').append(searchError);
}
```

SearchResults is the table name.

When a user searches, the search checks a database to see if what the user searchs actually exists in the data base if there is nothing in the database I need the unique error to be show. So if someone searches for a invalid country then I need the country error to be shown in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following as a callback to getting the search results:

```
$('#SearchResults:empty').append('<p>No results.</p>');
```